# jQuery Templates plugin and data persistence

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, plugins, persistence

I'm not quite sure what's happening, but all signs point me in this direction..
I have this fragment of code (working):

```
some_data = {"item":"value"};
$.get("some_template.php", function(template)
{
    $.tmpl(template, some_data).appendTo("#some_div");

    do_something_else();
});
//evil line
```

and #some_div gets populated...but, if at the "evil line" I put this:

```
some_data = {};
```

the #some_div shows empty.
It's there some kind of data persistence within the template plugin?
I'm supposed not to mess with some_data after being used?

**2011-07-22 Important!**
From what I've learned, the json object and the template are linked, so if I do this at the "evil line":

```
some_data = {"item":"new value"};
```

the template changes it's content even after it has been rendered. 
Does anybody know if there's a way to prevent this?

**SOLUTION!: see my comment on Brandon Boone's answer**
Example:

```
some_data = {"item":"value"};
$.get("some_template.php", function(template)
{
    $.tmpl(template, some_data).appendTo("#some_div");

    some_data = {}; //evil line

    do_something_else();
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help, but just to clarify, the json object and the template are Not linked. "`some_data = {};`" was getting executed before you ever reached "`$.tmpl(template, some_data).appendTo("#some_div");`" because `$.get(..)`'s callback function ("`function(template){...}`") is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `function(template){...}` is an asynchronous callback function. Meaning that your "evil line" will likely execute before the interior of this function is reached. So by the time you use some_data inside the function, it will already be empty.

Refactoring to:

http://jsfiddle.net/dq9es/

Will fix the issue

Comment: Hey Brandon! thanks for your reply. You'll see...you were right about the asynchronous but, it was the $.get function not the $.tmpl.

headache gone!! =)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you run

```
$.tmpl(template, {});
```

it is looping through the template for each piece of data you are passing it and filling the div accordingly. If you don't pass it any data it isn't looping through template and outputting html.

If you are just trying to load static html, I don't think templates are the solution.